# Inheritance , changes only in one child

Tags: c#, inheritance, addition

```
public List<string> clnc_EyeDR = new List<string>() 
                { "DR.David Rogers", "DR.Bill Loue", "DR.Jack Gersh" };
public List<string> clnc_E_Date = new List<string>() 
                { "Mon", "Wed", "Fri"}; 
public List<string> clnc_E_Time = new List<string>() 
                { "10:00-14:00", "14:00-18:00", "18:00-22:00"}; 
public List<string> clnc_E_Fee = new List<string>() 
                { "50", "55", "45" };  
public List<int> clnc_E_Available = new List<int>() 
                { 30, 20, 25 };
```

I have This list in class of father!Now I have administer class which is a child class! this class can add and remove doctors to those lists! patient cannot see these changes!:(

I am beginner programmer and I have learned to work with console application in C# but We have learned some basics about OOP in this class! For final project, we have to write a code about a clinic and we have to use inheritance! Now my question is : 
First I made a class as  a father and Then made 3 classes as a child. I define some lists in class of father as a list of doctors. I also define a function to add some doctors to list of doctors! And call this function in a child class! This changes show up in this child class but it does not show up in the rest of child class? Why and what should i do? Is that because of i did not call this function in child class?

Comment: Show you code, what have you tried.

Comment: Yeah, no code, no help

Comment: How can i attach my code here?

Comment: @SaraTajbakhsh Just copy and past it into the question.  There's also a button that will format it for you (basically every line has to start with at least 4 spaces)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081138/inheritance-c-sharp-help-me/45081203#45081203) below your post

Comment: "How can i attach my code here? " you mean you didn't read the [help] and [ask] before posting here?  You have to read the instruction manual carefully before you use a new product.

Comment: I actually have 4 classes. Class of father is named as clinic and I have 3 classes as a child which is named general doctor, specialist doctor and administer ! And I do not have patient class and there is not any connection ! So maybe I have to make a patient class! Patient just see the general doctors and specialist doctors and also can get an appointment from those! Please help me thank you!

Comment: And also I have a another question! How can I share my whole code here?

Comment: you can share you code via [this page](https://codeshare.io)

Comment: your doctor should not inherit from clinic! think of the real world, A clinic has properties that a doctor will never have, like doors, employees and so on. You should have a class general doctor and every special doctor should inherit from the general one. This is what inheritance is good for

Comment: Thanks so much ! That's Right! But what about doctor as an employee? Ket me explain my project here. My project wants us to define a clinic which has 2 department general and special department. These two department has general doctor in general department and specialist in special department and each department has eye dr, baby care dr, skin and hair dr, digestive disease dr. From general dr you can get appointment and request for referral letter for specialist. And in special department, specialist can  set time for surgery for a patient and patient can get an appointment!

Comment: And also this clinic work with 3 insurance company! We have to calculate each patient visit fee, surgery  payment with insurance and generate an invoice for patient ! Would you please help me ?

Comment: sounds like a big project. I cannot help you in the last detail. Try to think of the real world when implmenting your objects. Have a class `Doctor` with fields , properties and methods which every doctor needs!, then create special cases of doctors and inherit from the class `Doctor`. If you say ** clinic which has 2 departments** then in code this would be an object of type `Clinic` which has a property/field of type `GeneralDepartment Gen_Department` and a property/field of type `SpecialDepartment Spec_Department`, preferably both department classes would inherit from a  class `Department`

Comment: I share my whole code in code share! Would you please check it if you have time! I appreciate your help!

Comment: https://codeshare.io/24Aj4K

Comment: this is the link

Comment: @MongZhu it is really helpful! Thanks so much

Comment: @MongZhu you mean I should create two class which is father (doctor and department) and each of them has two child

Comment: the doctor class should have as much children as you have special cases of a doctor. You wrote you have 6 different doctors. So all of them should inherit from doctor. I wish you good luck with your project. Comments are not for long chat like discussions. If you have more question, please post new questions :)

Comment: if you think that my answer was helpful it would be cool if you could [accept my answer as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This way future visitors with the same problem can see that this question has a definite answer.

Answer (score 5):

> but it does not show up in the rest of child class?

Because everyone inherits it's own objects from the parent. Imagine you have 3 children and they inherit your hair. Now when you cut the hair of the first child,  why in the world would the haircut change of the other children? ;)

Every child inherits it's own set of properties which belong solely to the child! They are independent.

Inheritance does not mean that a real object of the parent is created when a child is created, but it means that the child object will have all properties defined **like** the parent, but they will belong to the child object. The children don't share the objects

Comment: Right! Let me take some photo and send it here!

Comment: @SaraTajbakhsh I don't need any family photos ;). Why do you want to change the list in the other children?

Comment: Funny but i have administer class and this class can add some changes such as add doctors to this list and then i need to show this to patient !

Comment: @SaraTajbakhsh then inheritance is not really the right approach. Imagine the real world, how get a patient access to the doctor? not by carrying around your own doctor list in your pocket...

Comment: @SaraTajbakhsh please follow [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45081138/edit) and copy your code into the edit window. It will allow you to change your current post. Don't forget to save the changes ;)

Comment: I know but we have to show changes to our instructor! I am beginner and I've just worked with console application

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Comment: @SaraTajbakhsh I understand. Go ahead and post your code. Then we can try to find a solution for you. Or at least drive you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Unless a member (like your list) is `static`, changes to it are not going to show up in all instances of your class, or more accurately put: making a member `static` is the only way to access a member that belongs to a class (rather than to instances of that class) through any of its instances.

When you instantiate a class, modifications you make to its members -- whether they are inherited from the base class, or defined in the derived class -- are not reflected in other instances of that class.

Comment: Actually the list is public because i need that list in all the classes!

Comment: `public` is an access modifier.  It's separate from `static`.  `static` members can be `public`.  `public` members don't have to be `static`.  They're independent.

Comment: You mean i have to use public static for this list ?